# QuickBooks Online Java SDK invoice creation always for the same customer

Tags: java, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I'm referring to version v3 of the API using the Java SDK (v2.2.1). I'm using a trial account for testing, and I have 6 customers stored. The first customer I created has display name 'Abe Lincoln'. Whenever I try to create invoices for a customer using their associated customer ID (retrieved from the API by querying the display name), the invoices are created successfully but every one of them is associated with the customer 'Abe Lincoln' !!

Here's the invoice creation code. I ran it with hardcoded values just to be sure:

```
Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
invoice.setDocNumber("DocNum");

ReferenceType customerRef = new ReferenceType();
customerRef.setValue("4");  // display name = 'Joe Bloggs'
invoice.setCustomerRef(customerRef);

Line line = new Line();
line.setAmount( new BigDecimal(50) );
line.setDetailType(LineDetailTypeEnum.SALES_ITEM_LINE_DETAIL);

SalesItemLineDetail salesItemLineDetail = new SalesItemLineDetail();
ReferenceType itemRef = customerRef;

itemRef.setName("ProductName");
itemRef.setValue("1");
salesItemLineDetail.setItemRef(itemRef);
line.setSalesItemLineDetail(salesItemLineDetail);

List<Line> linesList = new ArrayList<Line>();
linesList.add(line);
invoice.setLine(linesList);

invoice.setPrivateNote("PrivateNote");
batch.addEntity(invoice, OperationEnum.CREATE, idx + "");
```

...and after running this, an invoice is created in my account for the customer 'Abe Lincoln'. The display name for the customer with id "4" is actually 'Joe Bloggs'. I've tried it with the values 2 through to 6 (which are all valid for other customers) but no matter what the result is the same. Can anyone suggest what's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are overwriting value with 1 at later part.

```
ReferenceType itemRef = customerRef;

itemRef.setName("ProductName");
itemRef.setValue("1");
```

create a new ReferenceType object here...

```
ReferenceType itemRef = new ReferenceType();`
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I feel like I should explain myself. I replicated that behavior from an answer given to another question I had about invoice creation a while ago. It didn't make sense to me at the time, and I had changed it to create a new ReferenceType, but I was getting other errors previously and in a desperate attempt to fix them I reverted back to holding the same reference. Anyway, enough rambling, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the java devkit to debug mode as mentioned in the following docs.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0201_ipp_java_devkit_3.0/0006_logging#SDK_Logs

You can easily debug the issue by capturing and investigating the raw request/response XMLs.

Othewise, you can apiExplorer tool to query customer entity(for 'Abe Lincoln' and 'Joe Bloggs'). Please see if you have consistent DisplayName(as there are multiple name related attributes) and Id.

https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#Customer

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to debug further. I'm assuming you're a QuickBooks dev or heavy user at least. I know this is bad practice, but could you answer another quick question for me? Is it possible to mark an invoice as 'paid' using the Java SDK or API?

Comment: I need to check and get back. Invoice doc doesn't mentioned anything explicitly about it. You can check the behavior it by creating a corresponding payment.https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/invoice